# Download profile image from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

i am trying to download the facebook image profile with AsyncTask, however i get that the bitmap that downloaded is null and therefore i get a nullPointerExceprion.

this is my code:

```
private synchronized void downloadAvatar(final String user_id,final ImageView iv) {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                URL fbAvatarUrl = null;
                Bitmap fbAvatarBitmap = null;
                try {
                    fbAvatarUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+user_id+"/picture");
                    fbAvatarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fbAvatarUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return fbAvatarBitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {


                iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

(user_id) is a exist profile id -i checked it in the debug mode..

i get a nullPointerException at this line:

```
iv.setImageBitmap(result);
```

(result is null)

also, here is the logcat:

```
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at com.example.sal.ProfileActivity$15.onPostExecute(ProfileActivity.java:1998)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at com.example.sal.ProfileActivity$15.onPostExecute(ProfileActivity.java:1)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-12 14:16:40.140: E/AndroidRuntime(19304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Stupid question, is fbAvatarBitmap downloaded?

Comment: i think that image is corretly downloaded,i have another problem it says that i cant set image in the ImageView because only the main thread in hierarchy can touch its views...so how can i pass the ImageView to this AsyncTask and put the bitmap in it? thanks alot

Comment: Is the Asynktask being created from the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and tested it and it is working fine getting the image correctly ..

The log you put shows that the image is set to null, which means it failed to get the image from URL in the "try" part, can you please put logcat of try catch part, and if there is any exceptions arised before the NULL pointer one?

I also recommend that you set image inside the "try", so that it will be set only if succeeded to get the image, and in catch you can set a toast defining error ..

For now double check, you added internet permission, and show us complete log before the null pointer exception please...

Comment: you are right, i think tight now that the image is correctly downloaded, however i have another problem it says that i cant set image in the ImageView because only the main thread in hierarchy can touch its views...so how can i pass the ImageView to this AsyncTask and put the bitmap in it? thanks alot

Comment: yes, my mistake, views can't be mentioned in background.. so just in post execute double check if not null before setting image, you can add a toast if null:  if (result != null)
              iv.setImageBitmap(result);
              else
              //toast